# How to select random entry from table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to display a random last name of a person who entered into an employment contract in a specified month using the rand function

```
go
CREATE OR ALTER function [dbo].[User_Surname] 
(@mont int)
    returns nvarchar(50)
    begin
        Declare @surname nvarchar(50)
        Set @surname = (Select top(1)  surname from dbo.Tenants 
            inner join dbo.lease_agreements on Tenants.tenant_code = lease_agreements.tenant_code  
                where MONTH(lease_agreements.rental_start_date) = @mont and dbo.Tenants.tenant_code = (select * from randNumber))
        return @surname
    end
go
select dbo.User_Surname (1)
```

```
create or alter view randNumber as 
Select FLOOR((RAND() * (MAX(tenant_code + 1) - 1)) + 1) as value from Tenants
```

Comment: Dont use newid()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want only one tenant, use 'ORDEr BY RAND()`

As always with randomness, you could alos get 100 times the same tenant, especially when you have only a small number of tenants that fit the bill.

This will never be fast as the table needs to be full scanned, but at least you should have an index on (tenant_code  ,rental_start_date) so that it will be faster to select the correct tenants

```
CREATE OR ALTER function [dbo].[User_Surname] 
    (@mont int)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @surname nvarchar(50)
    SET @surname = (SELECT TOP(1) surname 
                    FROM dbo.Tenants 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.lease_agreements ON Tenants.tenant_code = lease_agreements.tenant_code  
                    WHERE MONTH(lease_agreements.rental_start_date) = @mont 
                    ORDER By RAND())
    RETURN @surname
END
```

Answer (score 0):

So what if tenant #42 has been removed?  If the random number function returns 42, then your query will yield nothing.

To fix this problem, an approach which would be quite difficult to correctly implement would involve a row-sequence-number column which is an integer which sequentially increments and does not contain gaps. In order to avoid a gap when a row is deleted, you must pick the last row from the table and give it the row-sequence-number of the deleted column. Consistently doing so without ever forgetting to do it seems like a tough proposition. Achieving this without concurrency problems when rows are being concurrently deleted also seems like a tough proposition. Furthermore, the possibility that the last row may be re-sequenced means that you cannot use an SQL SEQUENCE for issuing row sequence numbers, or that your RDBMS must support the ability to count-down on a sequence, which is a tough proposition.

A better approach would be to create a random number N between zero and the number of rows instead of the maximum row id number, and then to pick the Nth row from the table. That would be something like `SELECT BOTTOM 1 FROM (SELECT TOP N FROM...`

An SQL-only solution (involving no stored procedures) would be very inefficient. It would involve joining the table of interest with the random-number function, (just real random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0,) essentially creating a new table which also contains a random number field, then using ORDER BY the random field, and then using TOP 1 to get the first row. To achieve this, your RDBMS would be performing a full table scan, and creating an entire new sorted temporary table, and it would be doing that each time you ask for a row at random, so it would be preposterously inefficient.

A performance improvement on the above idea would be to permanently add the random number column to each row, (and to issue a new random number between 0.0 and 1.0 to each row later inserted,) and then use a SEQUENCE for issuing sequential row index numbers, so that each time you want a new random row you pick the next number N from the sequence, you compute its modulus by the number of rows in the table, and you get the Nth row from the table sorted by random-number-column. It will probably be a good idea to make that random number column indexed. The problem with this approach is that it does not truly yield records at random, it yields all records in random order. Truly yielding records at random means that the same row might be yielded twice in two successive queries. This approach will only yield a record again once all other records have first been yielded.